# SDWebImageを使用して取得した画像の高さ変更がうまくできない

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

SDWebimageで取得した画像をカスタムCell上のUIImageViewに表示させたのですが、 CGRectMake等で画像の高さを指定してもうまく効いてくれません。
現状、画像幅について仕様通りスクリーン幅になってますが、高さがいうことを効かず画像が縦長になっています。これをうまく高さ調整したいです。

FacebookやTumblerアプリのタイムラインのような、画像が画面幅にfixしたUIを実現させたいです。いくつかの方法を試したのですが、どれも納得のいくものではありませんでした。
同じ問題に遭遇した方、もしくは何かしら解決案がある方、相談にのっていただけたら幸いです。

## 実装について

1. 画像の取得には[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)を使用しています。
2. 画像のWidthはスクリーン幅、HeightはWidthの拡大・縮小比に合わせて動的に決定してます。なので、それぞれの画像は高さが異なります。
3. Storyboard上で、画像にはAutolayoutの制約を横幅0pxで左右つけてます。画像幅に関してはうまく実現できています。
4. 現状、SDWebimageのコールバックで画像の幅高さ等を決めてます。(効いていない)

## 試してみてうまくいかなかった方法

1. それぞれのCellで、画像の高さのAutolayout制約を加える。
2. それぞれのCellで、SDWebimageで取得した画像にFrameを設定する。

## うまくいったが納得いかない、もっといい方法があるのではないかという方法

1. それぞれのCellで、SDWebimageで取得した画像をリサイズして表示する。
   →Tableがスクロール時にかくつく、リサイズするので画質が悪くなる
2. APIから画像の高さも返すようにして、テーブル側で高さ計算する
   →きっともっといい方法があるはず

解決したいので、もしわかりにくい点がありましたら補足させてください。
お時間いただける方よろしくお願いします。